# Base64 Encoding Padding in C

Tags: c

I am writting a base64 encoder and decoder and have it almost completly functional, I just need to be able to pad the encoded data with equal signs if the number of input bytes does not round out to a multiple of 3. I am relativly new to C and am not sure how I would detect the number of bytes or pad the output accordingly. This is what I have so far

```
void encode(char* src, char* dest) {

    char base64[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    unsigned char first = (src[0] >> 2);

    unsigned char second = (src[0] << 4) | (src[1] >> 4);
    second = (second << 2);
    second = (second >> 2);

    unsigned char third = (src[1] << 2) | (src[2] >> 6);
    third = (third << 2);
    third = (third >> 2);

    unsigned char fourth = (src[2]);
    fourth = (fourth << 2);
    fourth = (fourth >> 2);

    dest[0] = base64[first];
    dest[1] = base64[second];
    dest[2] = base64[third];
    dest[3] = base64[fourth];

}
```

And my decoder method...

```
void decode(char* src, char* dest) {

    char base64[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    int i;
    int j;
    int index;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        index = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
            if (src[i] == base64[j]) {
                src[i] = index;
            } else {
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    char first = (src[0] << 2) | (src[1] >> 4);
    char second = (src[1] << 4) | (src[2] >> 2);
    char third = (src[2] << 6) | (src[3]);

    dest[0] = first;
    dest[1] = second;
    dest[2] = third;
}
```

If this is not enough and I need to also provide the rest of my code I can do so.

Comment: The `encode` function may not work well if `char` in your environment is signed. To let `encode` know the length to encode, pass the information via another argument.

Comment: You need to detect the end of the input.  Perhaps that's a null byte marking the end (but it probably isn't — you use Base64 encoding for binary data that can contain null bytes), but much more likely you tell your code how many bytes you have to encode.  If the number is 1 or 2 instead of 3, you have to handle the short count differently, adding the `=` sign (padding).  The decoding must recognize the padding and decode differently. It should probably indicate an encoding error if there aren't 4 bytes to decode, and if the values are not valid.  You could lose `first`, `second` and `third`.